# Как решить проблему «не найдены ссылочные сборки для NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0»?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Решил я декомпилировать DLL с помощью dnSpy и пересобрать в Visual Studio, но тут не пруха. Программа при сборке не находит sdk dotnet, хотя я установил всевозможные версии пакетов, пробовал с сайта, установщика, ничего не помогает.

Ошибка: не найдены ссылочные сборки для .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0. Чтобы устранить эту проблему, установите пакет разработчика (пакет SDK или пакет нацеливания) для этой версии платформы или перенацельте приложение. Пакеты разработчика для платформы .NET Framework можно скачать на странице https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]